# I can't upload files (>120M) on server from web page in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I cannot upload the files which are more than 120MB. I have set the progress bar for uploading file status.
For normal files (<120M), the half file will upload, but if we try to upload images, then it will upload successfully.
For large files(>120M), When I click on submit, the progress bar goes upto 9-12%, then it will start again from 0, and when it reach 9-12%, It fails.
I am sending the files using ajax.
I have change some values in php.ini file...

```
memory_limit = 1999M

post_max_size = 1800M

upload_max_filesize = 1200M

max_execution_time = 18000

max_input_time = 0
```

Now, anything I have to change in php.ini file?
The ajax & php code is given below...

AJAX:

```
function sendData() {
            var fl = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];
            var fData = new FormData();
            fData.append("file1", fl);
            var rqst = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rqst.upload.addEventListener("progress",prgss,false);
            rqst.upload.addEventListener("error",err,false);
            rqst.open("POST","file1.php",true);
            rqst.send(fData);
        }
        function prgss(ev) {
            var per = (ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100;
            document.getElementById("prgsBar").value = Math.round(per);
            $('#prgsCnt').text(Math.round(per));
        }
```

PHP (file1.php):

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $tName = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($tName, "files/$name"))
    {
        echo "done";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `post_max_size` has to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: I have already set it larger. ' post_max_size = 1800M ' and ' upload_max_filesize 1200M '.

Comment: which server you are using? if nginx then you might need to check the server config for **client_max_body_size**

Comment: Actually I am running my code on live server (Linux shared hosting plan).

Comment: In order to be sure that it's not related to that, you'd set `max_execution_time` to -1 (no limit).

Comment: I have tried it. But there no any change. @AnthonyB